# OpenCV detecting hexagon grid on a map

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, detection

I am trying to detect with OpenCv for Android hexagon fields of a map for a board game. The map looks something like that:

**[Sample map]**
[image]

I tried getting contours using only Value from HSV and I managed to get some of the hexagons, but unfortunately not all of them, I had mostly trouble detecting hexagons that had rivers or roads passing through them.

I managed to get something like that:

**[Detected hexagons]**

[image]

I even tried to make the borders thicker, but it didn't help a lot.
To detect all of the hexagons I thought of averaging the approximite size of the detected and then go on pixel by pixel trying to detect a change in the color (close to black). Later I would like to detect hexagons even on photos of a map, so then I couldn't really rely on the size of other hexagons.

What do you think would be the best way to solve this problem?

EDIT:
Thank you
I  just began to implement your idea and it works great, for now i got the horizontal lines:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deal with regular grid, so you just need to detect just a few, or even one, to compute all others. More will be better, because you'll be able to compute mean, and it will be more accurate. To find contours, it might be useful to find color gradient.

Comment: Thanks, you're right because no matter how I take the photo, the lines that are parallel will stay this way. I didn't think about it  because its hexagons and the grid is nit regular but i guess if I extend some of the borders I will be able set the posaition of others without even analysing an image. Should I dtect the hexagons the way I did or should I try to detect the lines with another algorythym

Comment: Also you can apply rotation (lines 60 (or 120) deg to each other) and apply the same method as you did for horizontak lines. Intersecrions will be the vertices of hexagons,